# Why do we need to read the list from right to left, when calculating the moving average window?

Tags: python

I am solving the following Leetcode design question: https://leetcode.com/problems/moving-average-from-data-stream/

Here is an accepted solution:

```
class MovingAverage:
    def __init__(self, size: int):
        self.size = size
        self.queue = []

    def next(self, val: int) -> float:
        size, queue = self.size, self.queue
        queue.append(val)
        # calculate the sum of the moving window
        window_sum = sum(queue[-size:])

        return window_sum / min(len(queue), size)
```

I understand it all, except for the `window_sum = sum(queue[-size:])` ; in particular, what does `queue[-size:]` do? I know it reads the `list queue` from right to left, but why is this necessary in this question? And when I take the minus sign away I get the wrong answer, why is this?

Comment: `queue[-size:]` to get last {size} elements in `quene`. Such as `queue[-3:]` means get last three elements in `quene`.

Comment: Thanks leaf, I did understand this. But why are we doing this in the solution? Why not take the first 3 elements?

Comment: Leaf, I understand it now- I initially misread the question